# Log all https requests from browser

Tags: proxy

I want to log all https URL requests including their referrer URL and preferably also the IP address of the server.

I expected I would be able to do this by installing Squid, but it seems, that it can only log setting up TCP tunnels for TLS:

```
1672400019.799 108971 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5402 CONNECT qa.sockets.stackexchange.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/198.252.206.25 -
1672400021.006      6 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 39 CONNECT cdn-static.ecosia.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.173.5.59 -
```

It is OK, if I have to add the proxy to my browser as a proxy.

Comment: Burp Suite? ...

Comment: For Firefox https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/networking/http/logging.html ?

Comment: Squid can do this, but you need to add your Squid as CA too.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I found no way of producing a referrer log.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Great. Where do I find a guide to set that up?

Comment: using a container: https://github.com/authsec/squid (untested by me, bugs go to the author)